# Install 18.04 - /home size?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation

I need to reinstall 18.04 (due to ongoing problems) and was wondering as to the best way to partition. I have a 1TB HD. I want a separate `/home` directory so I was wondering what's the best way to go about it to allow enough space for `/boot`, `/`, etc.? Right now my `/home` directory is 173.8 GB. Can I let Ubuntu take care of the other sizes when I get to the "Something Else" screen?

EDIT:  I don't believe the question is a copy as I would have skipped that answer in a search as it also deals with Windoze.

Comment: You don't need `/boot` but a separated `/home` has some advantages when reinstalling. So,  20 - 25GB for root is enough for a lot of software, use the rest for `/home`.

Comment: The "Something else" option is fully manual, or completely none-automatic. You, the user must select each partition's attributes, so, IMHO, "the best way" would be to do just that.

Comment: Root (/) is good to have around 25gb, /home depends on how much you think you will put in over the years.  Some people will be happy with only 100gb, others will need the rest of the 1tb drive or more.  When using the 'something else' pay attention to the numbers, you want to make the partitions the size you want.

Comment: Even if you don't have Windows, the above answer gives the correct sizes for Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia's answer is exactly what I was looking for ... plain and simple. Thanks! I don't believe the question is a copy as I would have skipped that answer in a search as it also deals with Windoze. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.